# xamarin forms geolocation won't ask for gps to be turned on if the it's off

Tags: xamarin.forms

i'm trying to get the current location of the phone and then set the google maps view accordingly but if i have the gps off, it will just thrown an error instead of asking me to turn it on.
i have the access fine and coarse location permissions on android.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

```
var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Best));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can detect whether GPS Location enable before you use it. I do one sample to check GPS isenbale or disable on Android platform for Xamarin.forms, the setting GPS location will open if GPS location disable.

Creating interface IGpsDependencyService in shared code.

```
 public interface IGpsDependencyService
{
    void OpenSettings();
    bool IsGpsEnable();
}
```

Implement this interface on Android Platform, the platform implementations must be registered with the DependencyService, so that Xamarin.Forms can locate them at runtime.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(GpsDependencyService))]
namespace FormsSample.Droid
{
 public class GpsDependencyService : IGpsDependencyService
{
    public bool IsGpsEnable()
    {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);
        return locationManager.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GpsProvider);
    }

    public void OpenSettings()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocat‌​ionSourceSettings);
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        try
        {
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);

        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityNotFoundException)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(activityNotFoundException.Message);
            Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, "Error: Gps Activity", Android.Widget.ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

To check GPS location, I use **Plugin.Permissions** to check location permission.

```
 private async void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //var results = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        //LabelGeolocation.Text = "Lat: " + results.Latitude + " Long: " + results.Longitude;
        bool IsGpsEnable = Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<IGpsDependencyService>().IsGpsEnable();

        if (!IsGpsEnable)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Location service Denied", "Can not continue,please go to setting to open location service and try again.", "OK");
            Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<IGpsDependencyService>().OpenSettings();

        }
        else
        {

            try
            {
                var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
                if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Need location", "Gunna need that location", "OK");
                    }

                    var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
                    status = results[Permission.Location];
                }

                if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    var results = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                    LabelGeolocation.Text = "Lat: " + results.Latitude + " Long: " + results.Longitude;
                }
                else if (status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Location Denied", "Can not continue, try again.", "OK");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                LabelGeolocation.Text = "Error: " + ex;
            }
        }     
    }
```

About checking GPS location on ios platform, you can take a look:

https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1257